# How to use Java Class and JMeter API Classes Inside JSR223 PostProcessor

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I am using JMeter to Extract data from JSON response (HTTP Request). I Used JSR223 PostProcessor. According to JMeter API,  extractWithJsonPath() Method in the JSONManager class can be used to extract data from JSON string.

when I try this, javax.script.ScriptException is Thrown saying that "Unknown class: JSONManager"

```
String jsonString = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString(); 
log.info(new JSONManager().extractWithJsonPath(jsonString , "$.data"));
```

I just tried .getClass() method in Java.lang.Object class and that is also not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

For this use jMeter JSON Extractor: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor